# How to use Acrylic Accent in Windows 10 Creators Update?

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-composition-api, fluent-design

I can't find any detailed document to use Acrylic Accent ([CreateBackdropBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Composition.Compositor)). I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208841/how-to-use-acrylic-accent-createhostbackdropbrush-in-windows-10-creators-upd) in StackOverflow which is somewhat useful but it doesn't help to get started. So please create a detailed answer to this post so that everyone can learn.

**Update:**

Microsoft has released an official [Acrylic material](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/style/acrylic) document

**Note:**

If anyone doesn't know about Acrylic Accent. Acrylic Accent is the new feature in Windows 10 Creators Update that allows the app background to be Blurred and Transparent.[image][image]

Comment: Please, could you insert the "windows-composition-api" tag for your question?   It helps finding easily your question.    Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## CREATOR UPDATE

#### XAML

You need to use a component that you put on the background of your app, let's say a `RelativePanel`

```
<RelativePanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" MinWidth="40" x:Name="MainGrid" SizeChanged="Page_SizeChanged"/>
<RelativePanel Grid.Column="0" Width="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid,Path=Width}" Background="#28000000"/>
<Grid>
    <!--Having content here, for example textblock and so on-->
</Grid>
```

The second `RelativePanel` is used to set the shadow color above the Blur.

### .CS

And then you can use the following code :

```
private void applyAcrylicAccent(Panel panel)
{
    _compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this).Compositor;
    _hostSprite = _compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
    _hostSprite.Size = new Vector2((float) panel.ActualWidth, (float) panel.ActualHeight);

    ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(panel, _hostSprite);
    _hostSprite.Brush = _compositor.CreateHostBackdropBrush();
}
Compositor _compositor;
SpriteVisual _hostSprite;
```

and calling it with `applyAcrylicAccent(MainGrid);`
You also will need to handle the SizeChanged event :

```
private void Page_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_hostSprite != null)
        _hostSprite.Size = e.NewSize.ToVector2();
}
```

Of course you will need to be on the Creator Update to run this, the CreateHostBackdropBrush() won't work on a mobile device, or in tablet mode.

Also, consider that the panel or grid that you set with a acrylic color won't be able to display any control (as far I've tested yet). So you need to use your relative panel without any control in it.

### Transparent Title bar

The transparency of the title bar could be set using the following code

```
ApplicationViewTitleBar formattableTitleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
formattableTitleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
CoreApplicationViewTitleBar coreTitleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
```

Here a example of what the above code generate (with some other things added too.)[image: Example]

## Fall Update 10.0.16190 and above

As Justin XL mention in an answer below, starting from the Build 16190 and above, developers have access to different Acrylic Brushes located at `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media` ([Acrylic API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.acrylicbrush)) and the guidelines from Microsoft : [Acrylic material guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/style/acrylic)

Comment: Can't we control the amount of blur? How to apply the same effect to title bar?

Comment: I have updated the answer for the transparent title bar. About the amount of blur. As far I know. It is not possible to change it

Comment: Always `_compositor` will be null. I think you forgot to add `_compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this).Compositor;` in the post. Transparent Title bar doesn't work. Title bar background becomes black while the background of the buttons remains white.

Comment: @VijayNirmal I've corrected the _compositor, thanks.
Also I updated the code for transparent title bar. I missed a copy paste. It works now

Comment: How to get the color shade of transparent? I did it with the below code.
`<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.25"/>
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>`
Is there any easy method? Also we should use `e` instead of `this` in  `ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(e).Compositor`

Comment: Well, I used a Relative panel for the background color (see XAML part), because I prefer the color, but it should work with the grid too. 
For me `ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this).Compositor` works well. It is adjustable in regard of what you are looking for

Comment: What happens if non-Windows 10 Creators Update machine? I think it will crash so we need to add Exception Handler.

Comment: @SvenBorden I tried your code as-is and I got a window with a black screen: http://imgur.com/a/T5i5a. I am running Build 15063, Creators Update release and SDK

Comment: Where does the `applyAcrylicAccent` is located? Do you set the accent to the panel?

Comment: @SvenBorden Here's my MainPage.xaml.cs: https://pastebin.com/TniAk00k and here's my MainPage.xaml: https://pastebin.com/UEjmybVL ... This is what I get: http://imgur.com/a/i49ni

Comment: @DemCodeLines Hey there. I used the code you posted and got good results (see: http://imgur.com/jPsigJ9). My guess is there's a problem with your Windows installation and not the code itself. Also maybe check what version your application is targeting?

Comment: @SonofNun I am running this in Virtual Box. Target is "Windows 10 Creators Update". Not sure why it won't render. Maybe it's Virtual Box, but I don't see what setting would enable it.

Comment: I was able to get it to work. Had to enable 3D Acceleration for VirtualBox

Comment: @DemCodeLines Great! I'm glad you got it working. :)

Comment: With this code, it works initially, but when the window loses focus the min/max/close buttons lose the acrylic texture. Then after a moment the entire window becomes opaque. Any idea how to keep the acrylic effect when the window is not focused?

Comment: Microsoft has released an official [Acrylic material](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/style/acrylic) document

Comment: @FactorMystic This is expected behavior. The window which is not in focus will lose the acrylic effect.

Comment: Also, This doesnt produce acrylic effect which combines noise,gaussian blur, exclusion blend and tint/overlay effects. it just produces the blurred visual of the background of the app

Comment: As Vijay asked above, how can we check, if the CreateHostBackdropBrush() Method is available on the device?

Comment: @MojoJojo Yes exactly, it looks like this acrylic for Creator Update is a first step before the Fall Update with noise, tint, & exclusion blend

Comment: @andy You can check the OS Version (have a look here https://www.suchan.cz/2015/08/uwp-quick-tip-getting-device-os-and-app-info/ ) 
Or you can have a look is Api Contract is present maybe

Comment: @Sven Borden thank you, i know how to check, if a API is present, but for which API do i exactly need to check, when i want to use CreateHostBackdropBrush() method on creators update? When i only check for composition API, then i think this is not correct, because this API exists also in Anniversary Uodate, but does not provide a CreateHostBackdropBrush() method.

Comment: @andy Using this method `public static bool IsMethodPresent(String typeName, String methodName)`

Comment: I think you missunderstood me. I want to check the following way: Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("API"). But i don't know, in which Namespace this API exactly is, because "Windows.UI.Composition.Compositor" is also available in the previous Anniversary Update, but does not provide a CreateHostBackdropBrush() method.

Comment: @andy API Namespace is `Windows.UI.Composition.CompositionBackdropBrush`

Comment: Thank you. Are you sure that this is correct? The CreateHostBackdropBrush() Method indeed is in the Windows.UI.Composition.CompositionBackdropBrush Namespace, but only in the Version 4 of the API Contract. So when i check this Namespace, it is also available on the Anniversary Update, but not the CreateHostBackdropBrush() Method.

Comment: @SvenBorden You can simply set the background color directly to Main `Grid`. You don't want additional `RelativePanel` to set the background color.

Comment: @VijayNirmal Yes, if you want the main background to have a certain color, but if you want to have the same effect as your "maps" app pictures, you will probably need a second `RelativePanel` in order to achieve it

Comment: @SvenBorden how can I find your background wallpaper?

Answer (score 12):

In the <strike>Creators Update</strike> Insider Preview *16193* (along with Windows 10 SDK *16190*), there's a new [`AcrylicBrush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.acrylicbrush) that you can apply directly onto your element just like a normal `SolidColorBrush`.

```
<Page xmlns:media="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Media" ...>
    <Page.Resources>
        <media:AcrylicBrush x:Key="HostBackdropBrush"
                            BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
                            TintColor="LightBlue"
                            TintOpacity="0.6"
                            FallbackColor="LightSkyBlue"
                            FallbackForced="False" />
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource HostBackdropBrush}" />
</Page>
```

Note you can change the `BackgroundSource` to `Backdrop` to sample from the app content instead of the content behind the app window. Also make sure you define an appropriate `FallbackColor` because you will lose the acrylic effect when the app window has lost focus or the device is in battery saver mode.

Comment: I get an error saying :  `Unknown type 'AcrylicBrush' in XML namespace 'using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Media`. I had updated `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` NuGet package to `5.3.3`, rebuild the project and created a new project that only target Creator Update. How did you manage to make it compile?

Comment: @SvenBorden which sdk are you targeting n what build are you running? I am on build 16193 with sdk 16190.

Comment: Im on build 16193 targeting SDK 15063

Comment: @SvenBorden Yeah I guess you will need the newer SDK 16190, thanks for pointing it out, I will update the answer.