# Trying to use Acyrilic Brush, but it says it can't find the resource? Running latest insider preview and SDK

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10

I'm currently trying to use the new Acrylic Brushes from this API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.acrylicbrush). I have the latest SDK (both regular and the insider sdk) installed and in my application the minimum and target are both set to build 16190. When I try to use:

```
 <Grid x:Name="rootGrid" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlAcrylicMediumHighWindowBrush}"></Grid>
```

I get the error that it can't find the resource SystemControlAcrylicMediumHighWindowBrush

My OS build is insider 16215.

Am I missing anything else to make this work?

Comment: I think that you don't have SDK that supports that. I am not sure if it is even available at all.

Comment: @IvanIčin I know it's available as I had this working on another machine (that I can't access right now). I'll have to look and see if there's one I missed

Comment: Can you try if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43699256/how-to-use-acrylic-accent-in-windows-10-creators-update/43972370#43972370) is available?

Comment: @JustinXL Sweet thanks I'll give that a shot! I'm hoping once these APIs have a full release they will be backwards compatible to the creators updates as well

Comment: For those reading this @JustinXL solution worked. This seems to be the way to do it until these APIs are fully released.