# How to apply fallback color to acrylic in creators update

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-composition-api, fluent-design

After following this post: [How to use Acrylic Accent in Windows 10 Creators Update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43699256/how-to-use-acrylic-accent-in-windows-10-creators-update)

I've successfully added acrylic to my app on the Creators Update. Unfortunately, when transparency is disabled in the color settings in Windows, my app's background is either a very dark gray in the Light Theme or almost completely pitch black in dark Theme despite the fact that I set the background of my grid that's above the relative panel that makes the window transparent to:  Background="{ThemeResource CommandBarBackground}".

Does anyone know how to implement the fallback color in the creators update so that when transparency is disabled, the background switches to the original background color that was set.

Comment: Looking at your answer, it says that it was using Windows 10 SDK 16190. I don't think it applies in the Creators Update SDK (15063) since there is no Acrylic Brush available in the Creators Update.

Comment: Oh sorry, yeah that is only available in *Fall* Creators Update. One way you can probably try is to subscribe to `Window.Current.Activated` and when `WindowActivationState` is `Deactivated`, show another background on top of your blur.

Comment: @JustinXL Your suggestion did help a bit because now the correct colors are showing when the app is not in focus. Unfortunately, when the app is in focus again, it shows the incorrect colors.

Comment: I wonder why it shows incorrect colors. You should have a rectangle that overlays your blur element and use the rectangle as a fallback background.

Comment: @ColinKiama are you trying to add transparency to XAML screens ? Is that option available in Creator's update?

Comment: @Apoorv I've already added transparency, there is a way for you to add it in the Creator's Update and it's discussed in the link the post I linked on this post.

Comment: @JustinXL It turns out I did forget the second rectangle, setting its the background does work as a fallback color but the transparency effect won't be easily visible without the  Alpha value and/or background opacity being reduced. It would be great if there was a way to detect when the transparent effects are enabled on the user's device or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to implement the fallback color in the creators update so that when transparency is disabled, the background switches to the original background color that was set.

There is an [AdvancedEffectsEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings#Windows_UI_ViewManagement_UISettings_AdvancedEffectsEnabled) property in [U​ISettings Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings) which indicates whether the system Transparency effects setting is enabled. When it returns `false`, you can reset the background to the original background color.

And there is also an [AdvancedEffectsEnabledChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings#Windows_UI_ViewManagement_UISettings_AdvancedEffectsEnabledChanged) event occurs when the system advanced UI effects setting is enabled or disabled. You can combine this event with `AdvancedEffectsEnabled` property and use them like the following:

```
UISettings uiSettings = new UISettings();
uiSettings.AdvancedEffectsEnabledChanged += UiSettings_AdvancedEffectsEnabledChangedAsync;

private async void UiSettings_AdvancedEffectsEnabledChangedAsync(UISettings sender, object args)
{
    if (sender.AdvancedEffectsEnabled)
    {
        await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            //TODO: Apply Acrylic Accent
        });
    }
    else
    {
        await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            //TODO: Reset Background
        });
    }
}
```

Please note, [AdvancedEffectsEnabledChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings#Windows_UI_ViewManagement_UISettings_AdvancedEffectsEnabledChanged) event may not raised in UI thread. To change the background color, we will need [Core​Dispatcher.RunAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher#Windows_UI_Core_CoreDispatcher_RunAsync_) method.