# Does Windows 10 Mobile support the Fluent Design System for UWP apps?

Tags: uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml, fluent-design

I'm developing a new UWP app with the Fluent Design System (Acrylic Background and reveal) but apart from being available on Windows 10 Desktop, I also want to publish the application to Windows 10 Mobile. Does Windows 10 Mobile support the Fluent Design System? Or do I have to develop another application just for Windows 10 Mobile without the Fluent Design System?

Comment: all windows 10 mobile installed minimum windows 10.0.15063 version will able to handle fluent design system or you can download that version of emulator for testing. Try target version min 15063 and min version to 14393(not support fluent design) so mostly mobile user can able to use your app. In summary 10.0.14393 (No Fluent) is the version available in almost all device and 10.0.15063 (Fluent Support) in some mobile device and 10.0.16299(More tools related to fluent design) not available in mobile currently. Now Make your choice.

Answer (score 4):

Windows 10 Mobile build 10.0.15063 (Creators Update) supports composition effects as well as in-app acrylic (see [How to use Acrylic Accent in Windows 10 Creators Update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43699256/how-to-use-acrylic-accent-in-windows-10-creators-update)) and reveal effects via the composition API.

However, it does *not* support the `AcrylicBrush` or `RevealBrush` classes, as those classes are only available in build 10.0.16299 (Fall Creators Update) or later, which is not available for mobile devices (the current feature branch is build 10.0.15254, which is also dubbed the "Fall Creators Update" but does not actually include the new APIs).

While it is possible to incorporate Fluent Design elements into your Windows 10 Mobile app for devices running the Windows 10 Mobile Creators Update, doing so is far more trouble than it's worth. You will need to avoid using `AcrylicBrush` and `RevealBrush` since they're not available to mobile devices, and you will need to do in-app acrylic and reveal effects the hard way.

You don't need to make a separate app for mobile; if your minimum target version is 10.0.15063 you can use [conditional XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/conditional-xaml) to serve a legacy resource dictionary to mobile devices and Fluent Design to PCs. If your minimum target version is an older version that doesn't support conditional XAML, you need to use `Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent()` to check for `AcrylicBrush` and/or `RevealBrush` and [merge the appropriate resource dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references#merged-resource-dictionaries) into your `Application.Current.Resources` manually.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is very helpful but I have a question!
I want the minimum requirement of my application to be the anniversary update for both devices (Desktop and Mobile), how do I make my application not have fluent design in anniversary update, and have fluent desing in creators update and fall creators update?

Answer (score 0):

To use this brush you should know that it works if:

1. > **Device family**  Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (introduced v10.0.16299.0)
2. > **API contract**   Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract (introduced v5)

More information 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.acrylicbrush