# Why is Microsoft emulator not showing in VS if both minimum and target versions are set to fall creators update?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-mobile, windows-phone-emulator

I'm developing a UWP app whose minimum and target versions are set to Fall Creators Update. However, when I check the run options, I don't see the emulator.

But when I created a new project where the minimum sdk version is set to anniversary, I now see the emulator.

So how do I enable the emulator in my project without lowering the minimum version?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2018/02/14/why-cant-i-deploy-my-uwp-app-with-net-standard-2-0-to-a-mobile-device-or-emulator/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no emulators for the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (build 10.0.16299) because the Fall Creators Update is not available for Windows 10 Mobile.

Windows 10 Mobile gets emulators for build 10.0.15254 that Microsoft *calls* the Mobile Fall Creators Update, but only in name. [It doesn't actually contain the Fall Creators APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47967369/does-windows-10-mobile-support-the-fluent-design-system-for-uwp-apps/47969615#47969615), and in all other respects is the same as the Creators Update (build 10.0.15063).

You cannot use APIs and features new to the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update in Windows 10 Mobile. Furthermore, Windows 10 Mobile is no longer getting any major new APIs and features, at least on the consumer side. If you need to support Windows 10 Mobile, your minimum version needs to be 10.0.15063 or lower.